# Who are the Dread Masters?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-the-old-republic

In the game you fight Dread Master Styrak and when he dies he says something along the lines of "5 remaining..." During the fight he also talks about his brothers and sisters.
Is there any reference to this in the Star Wars universe or are these characters a creation for SWTOR exclusively?

I have heard that when playing Imperial side on Belsavis you get to see the names of the rest of the Dread Masters. I have also heard that on the PTS there is an operation where you fight some of them.

Sorry guys... Wookieepedia ftw and all that but my question wasn't 100% clear I think. I was wondering if there is any history on theese big, scary baddies before the game anywhere? I have played through the story on both sides so I have seen the story and I know their names. What I stil don't know is their origin I guess. They are scary and powerful and almost omnipotent but so far nothing is known about them outside the SWTOR universe.

**What is the origin of the six Dread Masters - where did they come from and how did they become the "Dread Masters"?**

Comment: The Dread Masters are an invention of the game, so nothing about them existed before SWTOR. Their origins have not been revealed yet in-game or in any of the period-specific comics.

Answer (score 3):

From [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dread_Masters):

> The Dread Masters were six powerful human Sith Lords who served the Sith Emperor for centuries as prophets, generals and advisors. Their name was earned when they studied the power of the Phobis devices, artifacts that had driven even the most depraved Sith mad with terror. This power allowed the Dread Masters to destroy entire Galactic Republic fleets during the Great Galactic War, they had mastered the art of battle meditation to the point that they would inflict an awful, mysterious terror upon members of any given Republic cruiser. In order to avoid being compromised, they kept in constant motion in an Imperial dreadnaught that roamed the galaxy. With the help of an Elite Republic Special Forces Division team, Jedi Knight Jaric Kaedan infiltrated the dreadnaught and captured the Dread Masters. The Jedi Order publicly announced that the Dread Masters were killed but secretly they were imprisoned on Belsavis.

The names of the six were:

- Raptus
- Bestia
- Brontes
- Calphayus
- Styrak
- Tyrans

I haven't played the game *The Old Republic*, so I don't know anything about fighting them.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to SSumners answer I know a little about the story line where your character asks what it would be like to fight a dread master. I saw the walk through for it and the your characters partner at the time says. "The thought alone should be impossible". So apparently they are really strong!

That link will lead you to a walk through of the light and dark mission. If that didn't answer your question the youtube channel has almost all the story lines for the game. I hope that at least helps. Remember "these aren't ordinary sith" :P